# Picture in table cell does not show until it has been searched for in search bar

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a reusable table cell that uses the UITableViewCell's style preset that gives you a picture, a title and a subtitle.

I use add view to add a second picture at right side of cell.

This second picture has stopped displaying however, until I search for something and it shows up in search results.  Then it displays and it continues to display even after the search is complete.  The picture just doesn't display initially.

Here is method for cell.

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];      
        Items *item = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];        
        cell.textLabel.text = item.name;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = item.sub;
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.png"];
             //add image to right
        UIImageView *rightimage;
        rightimage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(225.0,0.0,80.0,45.0)];
         rightimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.png"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:rightimage];
       return cell;
    }
```

Here is code for search bar.

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];
    searchResults = [self.tableItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString 

    *)searchText
    {
        if ([searchText length] == 0) {
            _fetchedResultsController = nil;
        }
        else {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[cd] %@", searchText];
    [[_fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] setPredicate:predicate];
    [[_fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] setFetchLimit:50];
        }

        NSError *error;
        if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }

        [[self tableView] reloadData];
    }
```

EDIT: As an added twist, when you type second letter in search box, image disappears.

Comment: haven't you tried to first add imageView to view hierarchy and THEN set image? I mean switch rightimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.png"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:rightimage];

Comment: Just tried.  Same issue.